# Why does acceleration not depend on mass down an incline?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, acceleration, friction

I understand the net force acting on toy car traveling down an incline is:

F = mg sin θ - μ mg cos θ

a = F/m

Hence mass cancels out leaving: a = g(sin θ - μ cos θ).

Intuitively I can't understand why this happens. My logic is that a toy car with larger mass has a larger gravitational force acting on it, but it also has more inertia, hence regardless of mass the toy car should accelerate at the same rate. That is assuming there is no friction.

As friction is dependent on the normal force, and mass affects the normal force. The toy car with larger mass experiences more friction. As a result this should mean that the acceleration of a toy car with larger mass is less, contradicting the formula above.

Could someone explain where the flaw in my logic is?

Comment: What is $\mu$ in the equation? Generally that would be the coefficient of kinetic friction, but that would mean the toy car is sliding down the incline instead of purely rolling. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

A Toy car with more mass down an incline experiences more friction **force** alright, but also more gravitational force to overcome the friction. These **forces** depend on mass linearly, meaning more the mass, more the force.

Now if you can enforce the condition: $force=a*mass$, then you are automatically getting an acceleration that is constant.

If you force were to be constant, then you'd get an acceleration inversely proportional to mass. If your force were proportional to $mass^2$, then your acceleration would linearly depend on mass, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> The toy car with larger mass experiences more friction.

That's not necessarily true. A car that is freely *rolling* straight down the fall line of a slope should not experience *any* friction between its tires and the surface. It probably will experience some friction between its axles and the bearings in which they rotate, and it probably will experience some [*rolling resistance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance), but both of those forces can be made arbitrarily small if you use the right materials and you take enough care in machining the surfaces. They can't be made to completely disappear, but they can be made small enough that they are overwhelmed by the terms in the car's equation of motion that depend on gravity and inertia.

Answer (score 0):

There are two assumptions inherent in the question.

First : The formula you have given applies when object is sliding down the incline. So wheels are not involved! It is better to talk about blocks rather than cars. If wheels are involved then rotation motion needs to be considered.

Second : We are assuming that $\mu$ is same for both surface. That is, the two surfaces are equally rough. Otherwise the block which is less rough will accelerate faster.

Coming to the question...

You have rightly pointed out that the car with more mass will have more normal and friction. But more force is required to slow down an object with more mass (inertia). Smaller object requires less force! In the end effect of mass cancels out just as in last case.